# Holomorphicity of an integral function

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am looking for a way to prove that the the function 
\begin{equation}
F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}dx
\end{equation}
is holomorphic for all $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\Re(a) > 0$. I don't really know how to apply Morera's theorem on this example, or whether it is the right approach. All hints are welcome.

Comment: What's wrong about an explicit evaluation, leading to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ for any $a$ such that $\text{Re}(a)>0$?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know. My professor proved that for $a > 0$, you may write that $F(a) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} $. Then he sets $G(a) = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\log z}$ for $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}^-$. Then he used analytic continuation to prove that $F$ and $G$ are equal. I merely wanted to to check that $F$ is holomorphic (in order to justify the usage of analytic continuation).

Comment: That's $\log a$ instead of $\log z$. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true when the interval of integration is finite, i.e. for
$$F_R(z) = \int_{-R}^R e^{-zx^2}dx.$$
What you want to do is show that the integral converges uniformly on strips of the form $\textrm{Re}(z) > \delta$. Any triangle $T$ in the half-plane $\textrm{Re}(z) > 0$ is contained in such a strip. We want to show that
$$\int_TF = \int_T\lim_{R \to \infty}F_R = 0,$$
as then $F$ is holomorphic by Morera's theorem. The uniform convergence allows us to switch the integral and the limit, thus
$$\int_TF = \lim_{R \to \infty}\int_TF_R.$$
But since $F_R$ is holomorphic, the right-hand side integral is equal to zero by Goursat's theorem, thus the limit is also zero.

Comment: What is the relevance of a triangular contour?  Any rectifiable closed curve suffices.

Comment: This is just the version of Morera's theroem I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{a}}F(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\bar{a}}e^{-ax^2}dx=0
\end{equation}
iff ${\bf Re}\,a > 0$.